# Efficient string parsing in JS: How to create a substring which does not allocate a new string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have large messages coming over the websocket that I'd like to parse with a regex (for simplicity).

The regex recognizes the format of the header, and upon reading the length field, we then know where the next segment lies, and I can run the regex on that portion.

However, since my entire message might be huge (say... 10MB) and consisting of many many segments (say... 1000, where the average segment is a little under 1K in length), then naively slicing the main message to pass it back to `re.exec()` at the next location seems like it will result in a ton of GC thrashing, if not an allocation of gigabytes just for the raw string content.

I wonder if there are any regex related functions which allow me to specify the index to start running the regex at? `exec` and `search` don't let me do this.

Comment: You could run the regex on a substring starting at whatever index you want to use.

Comment: why `str.substring(1, 4);` does not work?

Comment: Why do you think that creating a substring will allocate new memory? Since strings are immutable in JS, this could easily have been optimized in an implementation. Do you have any actual performance problems?

Comment: Docs don't make it clear if `substring` creates a new instance of a string or if it is able to reference the original string. Every single other substring method does specifically say that it creates a new string, however, and those i definitely need to avoid

Comment: JavaScript provides no way to control how string values are managed. You might want to look into using typed arrays, though a 10MB string might exceed the size browsers are willing to allow.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 defines a "sticky" flag on RegExps, which allows to check, if string starts with regexp at specific position:

```
var position = 3;
var string = "la-la-la";

var re = /\d+/y;
re.lastIndex = position;
var match = re.exec(string);
//... do something with match
```

There is a discussion about this:
http://esdiscuss.org/topic/proposal-for-exact-matching-and-matching-at-a-position-in-regexp

Comment: Did you read the other two answers? `lastIndex` exists and works and has done so for years. Also, holy crap that is a long discussion.

Comment: @StevenLu: The sticky flag however makes the match more efficient, because the regex will need to match exactly (and only) where the `lastIndex` says it should - while today it will examine the rest of the string if it didn't match right away. It's like an anchored match: `/^regex/.test(str.slice(n))`.

Comment: can't I accomplish this by setting the lastIndex myself?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that `RegExp.prototype.exec` handles this for you, so you just keep passing the original string in and it will only start searching starting at the place it last stopped.

This is not exactly ideal for me since it does a whole bunch of extra parsing than I need it to (it will parse the entire segments' contents), though. I think I can just "reach in" and push the `lastIndex` forward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, but not through arguments of a function. Instead, you can utilize the [`.lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) of the RegExp object (which needs to have the *global* flag set). The `match`, `replace`, `exec` and `test` methods will respect this value.

Your code might therefore look like this:

```
var re = /header:…length:(\d+)/g;
for (var m; m=re.exec(re); ) {
    var len = parseInt(m[1], 10);
    re.lastIndex += len;
    …
}
```